# Golang support to VSTS Git

Tags: go, azure-devops

I want to start a `Go` project in our team's VSTS. After creating the new repository, how can i use the command `go get` to get the copy of the repository like using in github?

I find a workaround about [golang with visualstudio.com git repos](http://ppanyukov.github.io/2017/02/01/golang-with-vsts-repos.html). Is there any other better solution?

Comment: That workaround similar to github private repos, found here https://gist.github.com/shurcooL/6927554. So looks like good solution for using `go get ...`

Comment: There are a couple of issues raised against vsts about this [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34888885-support-repos-for-golang-by-providing-a-url-alias) and [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20364613-add-golang-support-to-vsts-git), go vote!

Comment: @ChrisDrew voted it before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main question to use `go get` to get the packages and dependencies from VSTS git repo is the **credential issue**. So solutions should be separate with the ways provider credential to VSTS git repo. Options as below:

1. **Authentication with PAT**

   As the [link](http://ppanyukov.github.io/2017/02/01/golang-with-vsts-repos.html) you showed, you can auth with PAT.

   First,create a [personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts), then you can add PAT in the global `.gitignore` file:

   ```
   [url "https://Personal%20Access%20Token:PAT@account.account.com"]
   ```
2. **Authentication with alternate credential**

   Enable and set [alternate authentication credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/auth-overview?view=vsts#alternate-credentials), then add below line in global `.gitignore`:

   ```
   [url "https://SecondaryUserName:SecondaryPassword@account.visualstudio.com"]
   ```
3. **Authentication with SSH**

   As  Oleksandr mentioned, you can use SSH protocol instead.

   First, create a [SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/auth-overview?view=vsts#ssh-key-authentication) key and add it to VSTS, then you can add below line in global `.gitignore`:

   ```
   [url "ssh://account@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:22"]
   ```

Then you can use the command `go get <VSTS git repo URL>` to download and install packages and dependencies.

Comment: Useful info but I think the biggest problem is not credentials but the problem of vsts import paths, see [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34888885-support-repos-for-golang-by-providing-a-url-alias), [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20364613-add-golang-support-to-vsts-git) and [here](http://ppanyukov.github.io/2017/02/01/golang-with-vsts-repos.html)